# Lambda expression for nested foreach

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, lambda

how can I write lambda expression for the following nested foreach loops:

```
var temp= new List<Items>();
foreach (var item in dto.Items)
{
    temp.Add(item);
    foreach (var child in item.Children)
    {
      temp.Add(child);
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you *only* want the top level item and their children? What about the "grandchildren"? Does the order matter?

Comment: I just want top level item and their children. Order is not matter.

Answer (score 5):

```
dto.Items.SelectMany(item => item.Children).Concat(dto.Items);
```

should do it.

Edit:

As xanatos mentioned, if you want to have the same order as your loops produce, you should use this instead:

```
dto.Items.SelectMany(item => new[] { item }.Concat(item.Children))
```